# referenced in section `.rodata' of

Tags: c++, linux, linker

Hey friends
I am stuck at a serious linking error, I am getting an error like this `referenced in section .rodata' of xxx defined in discarded section .text._xxx.`

This is how I am compiling my program

```
   g++  main.o CPQENReportBB1.o CPQENReportBB2.o CPQ10minRecord.o  PQ10minconfiguration.o  ENReportConfig.o CPQFreeRecording.o CPQFreeHistogramReport.o
```

I have 8 files, it is compiling correctly but while linking I get the previously mentioned error.
 (i am using g++ version 3.4.3)
In two files I am getting this error message; I tried to shuffle the files in linking but then it is giving error in another two files. 
Please give any suggestion to solve this. I am using c++ templates

Comment: Check this: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16625. In other words: can you try with newer GCC?

Comment: sorry i am not getting what you are saying. if possible tell me this error is due to some problem in the code or it is bug in the compiler

Comment: Could be compiler bug. See the link. Try never version of compiler.

Comment: gcc 3.4.3 is ancient (turned 8 years two weeks ago)

Answer (score 1):

2 possible reasons:

1. the file format and the machine architecture.
2. the use of `__attribute__((section))`